# How to fix unstable build on buildfarm for noetic because of CMP0048?

Tags: ros, catkin, buildfarm

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have just released my package on Neotic and the buildfarm [reports](http://build.ros.org/job/Ndev__ixblue_ins_stdbin_driver__ubuntu_focal_amd64/1/) an unstable build on `Ndev_*` because of CMake warning [CMP0048](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.15/policy/CMP0048.html) than means that `VERSION` is not provided in the `project()`.

From the console output:

```
16:09:34 CMake Warning (dev) at CMakeLists.txt:2 (project):
16:09:34   Policy CMP0048 is not set: project() command manages VERSION variables.
16:09:34   Run "cmake --help-policy CMP0048" for policy details.  Use the cmake_policy
16:09:34   command to set the policy and suppress this warning.
16:09:34 
16:09:34   The following variable(s) would be set to empty:
16:09:34 
16:09:34     CMAKE_PROJECT_VERSION
16:09:34     CMAKE_PROJECT_VERSION_MAJOR
16:09:34     CMAKE_PROJECT_VERSION_MINOR
16:09:34     CMAKE_PROJECT_VERSION_PATCH
16:09:34 This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.
```

I have checked other ROS packages and they don't seem to provide a version in their `CMakeLists.txt` nor set the `CMP0048` policy explicitly.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/361001/how-to-fix-unstable-build-on-buildfarm-for-noetic-because-of-cmp0048?/) by [rreignier](https://answers.ros.org/users/21983/rreignier/) on ROS Answers with karma: 544 on 2020-09-04

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

To avoid the warning with newer CMake versions you want to bump the minimum CMake version declared in the package. ROS packages for active distros use the following:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0.2)
```

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2020-09-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 7

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [rreignier](https://answers.ros.org/users/21983/rreignier/) on 2020-09-04**:
Great, thank you!

**Comment by [Markus Bader](https://answers.ros.org/users/390/markus-bader/) on 2020-12-18**:
Yes this works, but I am getting an error if I am using 3.0.2 with meta packages

**Comment by [sloretz](https://answers.ros.org/users/23470/sloretz/) on 2020-12-18**:
If you're getting an error due to metapackages, it means the version of catkin_pkg is too old. Upgrade that `sudo apt upgrade python3-catkin-pkg`. You need at least version 0.4.16 so it has this fix: https://github.com/ros-infrastructure/catkin_pkg/pull/274